# How do I draw a curve through tree points in Android?

Tags: android, graphics

I need to connect three points by a smooth curve. I've looked at the same questions already answered on StackOverflow but they all suggest using `Path.quadTo()`. I do not understand why this is considered a correct answer as Bezier curve is only approaching middle (control) point but not going through it. In my case I have to go exactly through it. So how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

True, what you need is Catmull Rom splines which are guaranted to go through each point. However, I don't know any function in the Android API to draw them. You could also "trick" the quadTo function and pass it a virtual middle point that you compute according to the current point and the next one.

Comment: Thanks for a clue, I've searched Internet thoroughly and have ended with the following computation of the control point for quadTo:

    // interpolate three points with second point at specified parameter value
    int[] interpolate(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, double t)
    {
      double t1 = 1.0 -t;
      double tSq = t * t;
      double denom = 2.0 * t * t1;
     
      int cx = (int) ((x1 - t1 * t1 * x0 - tSq * x2) / denom);
      int cy = (int) ((y1 - t1 * t1 * y0 - tSq * y2) / denom);
           
      return new int[] {cx, cy};
    }

Comment: @AndreyNovikov you should post it as answer to help others

Answer (score 0):

What about the cubicTo (or rCubicTo if you need it from a relative point) function?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#cubicTo(float, float, float, float, float, float)

Comment: cubicTo also uses Bezier splines, which do not provide what he needs.

Answer (score -1):

[Here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/canvas-from-scratch-advanced-drawing/) is a very nice, illustrated howto for javascript, but all the used methods are usual and there is an analogue in Androids [Path Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#cubicTo%28float)