# catmull-rom splines for Android

Tags: java, android, curve, spline, catmull-rom-curve

I'm trying to find a way to implement catmull-rom splines on the android platform for the purpose of smoothly drawing a line through n points.  Ideally I would be able to adapt cubic beziers via the Path and its cubicTo method as alluded to in this thread: [How do I draw a curve through tree points in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712003/how-do-i-draw-a-curve-through-tree-points-in-android)

Unfortunately, I wasnt able to follow the implementation there so I'm hoping somebody out there has already done this and can share a few lines of sample code.

Thanks!