# How to make line with rounded (smooth) corners with AndroidPlot

Tags: android, androidplot

I have a small problem with ploting my graph. On a picture below is what I have already done.

---

The graph should represent the actual signal strength of available Wi-Fi network(s). It's a simple `XYPlot` here data are represented with `SimpleXYSeries` (values are dynamically created).

Here is a little snippet of code (only for example):

```
plot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.simplexyPlot);
series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(series1Numbers),
SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "Link 1");
f1 = new LineAndPointFormatter(color.getColor(), null,
Color.argb(60, color.getRed(), color.getGreen(), color.getBlue()), null);
plot.addSeries(series1, f1);
```

The example in the picture is a dynamic simulation of dB changes. Everything works, I guess, correctly, but what I want to achieve is to have line with "rounded" corners (see the picture to see what I mean).

I already tried to customize LineFormatter:

```
f1.getFillPaint().setStrokeJoin(Join.ROUND);
f1.getFillPaint().setStrokeWidth(8);
```

But this didn't work as expected.

[image]

Note: The [Wifi Analyzer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer) application has a similar graph and its graph has the rounded corners I want. It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You might find this post helpful, http://stackoverflow.com/a/7608516/2291915. getFillPaint() returns android's Paint object and from there you can use the Android methods to achieve the effect you desire. Best of luck.

Comment: @buczek thanks buddy but it didn't work as i hoped. But thanks for your opinion.

Comment: Answer updated with screen of desired graph. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [Path.cubicTo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#cubicTo%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29) method. It draws a line using cubic spline algorithm which results in the smoothing effect you want.

Checkout the answer to a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287949/android-how-to-draw-a-smooth-line-following-your-finger), where a guy is talking about cubic splines. There is a short algorithm showing how to calculate input parameters for `Path.cubicTo()` method. You can play with divider values to achieve required smoothness. For example, in the picture below I divided by 5 instead of 3. Hope this helps.

[image: Example of a polylyne drawn using Path.cubicTo() method]

I have spent some time and implemented a `SplineLineAndPointFormatter` class, which does the stuff you need in androidplot library. It uses same technics. Here is how androidplot example applications looks like. You just need to use it instead of `LineAndPointFormatter`.

[image: Androidplot example with SplineLineAndPointFormatter]

Here is code example and the class I wrote.

```
f1 = new SplineLineAndPointFormatter(color.getColor(), null, 
      Color.argb(60, color.getRed(), color.getGreen(), color.getBlue()), null);
plot.addSeries(series1, f1);
```

Here is the class doing the magic. It is based on version 0.6.1 of [androidplot](http://bitbucket.org/androidplot/androidplot) library.

```
package com.androidplot.xy;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.RectF;

import com.androidplot.ui.SeriesRenderer;
import com.androidplot.util.ValPixConverter;

public class SplineLineAndPointFormatter extends LineAndPointFormatter {

    public SplineLineAndPointFormatter() { }

    public SplineLineAndPointFormatter(Integer lineColor, Integer vertexColor, Integer fillColor) {
        super(lineColor, vertexColor, fillColor, null);
    }

    public SplineLineAndPointFormatter(Integer lineColor, Integer vertexColor, Integer fillColor, FillDirection fillDir) {
        super(lineColor, vertexColor, fillColor, null, fillDir);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<? extends SeriesRenderer> getRendererClass() {
        return SplineLineAndPointRenderer.class;
    }

    @Override
    public SeriesRenderer getRendererInstance(XYPlot plot) {
        return new SplineLineAndPointRenderer(plot);
    }

    public static class SplineLineAndPointRenderer extends LineAndPointRenderer<BezierLineAndPointFormatter> {

        static class Point {
            public float x, y, dx, dy;
            public Point(PointF pf) { x = pf.x; y = pf.y; }
        }

        private Point prev, point, next;
        private int pointsCounter;

        public SplineLineAndPointRenderer(XYPlot plot) {
            super(plot);
        }

        @Override
        protected void appendToPath(Path path, final PointF thisPoint, PointF lastPoint) {
            pointsCounter--;

            if (point == null) {
                point = new Point(thisPoint);
                point.dx = ((point.x - prev.x) / 5);
                point.dy = ((point.y - prev.y) / 5);
                return;

            } else if (next == null) {
                next = new Point(thisPoint);
            } else {
                prev = point;
                point = next;
                next = new Point(thisPoint);
            }

            point.dx = ((next.x - prev.x) / 5);
            point.dy = ((next.y - prev.y) / 5);
            path.cubicTo(prev.x + prev.dx, prev.y + prev.dy, point.x - point.dx, point.y - point.dy, point.x, point.y);

            if (pointsCounter == 1) { // last point
                next.dx = ((next.x - point.x) / 5);
                next.dy = ((next.y - point.y) / 5);
                path.cubicTo(point.x + point.dx, point.y + point.dy, next.x - next.dx, next.y - next.dy, next.x, next.y);
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void drawSeries(Canvas canvas, RectF plotArea, XYSeries series, LineAndPointFormatter formatter) {

            Number y = series.getY(0);
            Number x = series.getX(0);
            if (x == null || y == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("no null values in xyseries permitted");

            XYPlot p = getPlot();
            PointF thisPoint = ValPixConverter.valToPix(x, y, plotArea,
                    p.getCalculatedMinX(), p.getCalculatedMaxX(), p.getCalculatedMinY(), p.getCalculatedMaxY());

            prev = new Point(thisPoint);
            point = next = null;
            pointsCounter = series.size();

            super.drawSeries(canvas, plotArea, series, formatter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i need graph and not Canvas to use.

Comment: I have just updated by answer by adding SplineLineAndPointFormatter, which does the same for androidplot library. You can add this class to your project and use as described.

Comment: Hello i have a little problem. I copied your stuff and error i did give: `The method drawSeries(Canvas, RectF, XYSeries, LineAndPointFormatter) of type SplineLineAndPointFormatter.SplineLineAndPointRenderer must override a superclass method` same with `appendToPath`

Comment: Which androidplot version are you using? I took the actual one (master branch), directly from https://bitbucket.org/androidplot/androidplot/

Comment: Do you have some jar?

Comment: Now, im getting NullPointerExeption at `super.drawSeries(canvas, plotArea, series, formatter);`

Comment: It looks null-values are not allowed in the constructor anymore. The code below worked for me. `new SplineLineAndPointFormatter(Color.rgb(90, 90, 90), Color.rgb(80, 80, 80), Color.rgb(20, 20, 20), FillDirection.TOP);`

Comment: I assume, that is the place where null-values were used, right? Can you use a transparent color instead?

Comment: You need to define a paint with `Style.FILL` and set it to formatter using `setFillPaint()` method. I tried to use `configure()` method to set FillPaint, but it didn't work. Maybe they broke it somehow. Keep `FillDirection.BOTTOM` in constructor too.

Comment: I included the class into androidplot library, recompiled it and uploaded to the server. Now you can download library and use the class from it. If you want to re-build the class, you need to clone the library from gitbucket, add `SplineLineAndPointFormatter` to it and recompile. This appears to be the right way to include it into the project. Here is the official snapshot + `SplineLineAndPointFormatter`: http://halfbit.de/d/androidplot-core-0.6.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: FillDirection.BOTTOM made a trick! Thanks you, and now, only question. its possible (in some way) make titles above lines (look at question). Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't find this option in library's source code. I would say it's not supported.

Comment: Hello man. I have one question. How can i change stroke width? it seems it doesnt work with setStrokeWidth(). Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You create a `Paint` with style `Paint.STROKE` and call `setStrokeWidth()` on it. Just make sure you set it using `SplineLineAndPointFormatter.setLinePaint()`.

Comment: The problem with using cubicTo this way is that it draws a line that "overshoots".  For example, looking at the graphic above you can see that the highest actual yval is 8 but the line drawn actually goes as high as ~8.2.  There's a [BezierLineAndPointRenderer](http://androidplot.com/javadoc/0.6.0/com/androidplot/xy/BezierLineAndPointRenderer.html|BezierLineAndPointRenderer) which uses quadTo for similar effect but suffers from the same flaw.  The ultimate solution is probably to use [Catmull-Rom Splines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602584/catmull-rom-splines-for-android).

Comment: @beworker Hello my friend. I need help. do you have still that library you updaded for me (with spline). I reinstalled pc and lost it...thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sajmon Sorry man, I don't have it either. Just take actual library, put the class above into it and compile. It will work.

Comment: 99.9% of users  should *NOT* do this.  The full rational and a more correct solution is available in my answer below.

Answer (score 8):

**1-** I guess that you only use a few points to draw graphs of signals. All graph/chart applications try to connect points with direct lines and then your chart will be shown. So if you only use three points, your graph will looks like a triangle! If you want your graph to be curved, you have to add more points. Then it comes out like a curve.

**2-** Or you can find any library that can draw `sin` graph, for example [`GraphView Library`](http://android-graphview.org/). Then try to draw this function:

[image]

So it looks like to this:

[image]

Then translate it to `(a,0)`, so result seems like what you want.

**3-** And another way, you can use built in `Math.sin` in Java:

Chose for example 1000 point in range `a` to `b` and compute value of above function for each point and finally create a `path` and show them in a canvas.

You can use [quadTo (float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#quadTo%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29) that simplify drawing `quad curves` for you. The documentation says:

> Add a quadratic bezier from the last point, approaching control point
>   (x1,y1), and ending at (x2,y2). If no moveTo() call has been made for
>   this contour, the first point is automatically set to (0,0).
>
> Parameters 
>   
>   x1    The x-coordinate of the control point on a quadratic curve 
>   y1    The y-coordinate of the control point on a quadratic curve 
>   x2    The x-coordinate of the end point on a quadratic curve 
>   y2    The y-coordinate of the end point on a quadratic curve

Finally, I add a simple class that extends `View` and can draw a curve that looks like what you want:

```
public class SinWave extends View {

    private float first_X = 50;
    private float first_Y = 230;
    private float end_X = 100;
    private float end_Y = 230;
    private float Max = 50;

    public SinWave(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint paint = new Paint() {
            {
                setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
                setStrokeWidth(0.7f);
                setAntiAlias(true);
                setColor(0xFFFF00FF);
            }
        };
        final Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(first_X, first_Y);
        path.quadTo((first_X + end_X)/2, Max, end_X, end_Y);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
}
```

The result must look like this:

[image]

You can add more methods to the class and change it to increase performance!

Comment: @ can you provide some code? im not good in math enough. i dont like math. thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi man, im here. So its nice but this is paint and i need to do it in some graph API. Could you do in in especially in AndroidPlot? thanks (sorry that im writing now, im busy in last days).

Comment: Ok man. i will give you bounty because it works but its not what i wanted. i'll continue to looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In some simple cases, this could help:

```
mPaint.pathEffect = CornerPathEffect(radius)
```

even in combination with

```
path.lineTo(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's always been a smooth line renderer in Androidplot: BezierLineAndPointRenderer, which like the implementations above uses Android's built in Bezier drawing routines **cubicTo(...)** & **quadTo(...)**.  The problem is that using Beziers to draw smooth lines in this way creates a false line that overshoots the actual control points by varying amounts, which you can see happening if you look closely at the image above.

The solution is to use the Catmull-Rom spline interpolation, which is now finally supported by Androidplot.  Details here: http://androidplot.com/smooth-curves-and-androidplot/

Answer (score 0):

Just use ChartFactory.getCubeLineChartView instead of ChartFactory.getLineChartView using achart engine

Answer (score -1):

try this:

> ```
> symbol = new Path();
> paint = new Paint();
> paint.setAntiAlias(true);      
> paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
> paint.setColor(-7829368);  
> paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);    // set the join to round you want
> paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);      // set the paint cap to round too
> paint.setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(10) );
> paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);       
>
> symbol.moveTo(50.0F, 230.0F);         
> symbol.lineTo(75.0F, 100.0F);
> symbol.lineTo(100.0F, 230.0F);
> ```

most of the info found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608362/how-to-draw-smooth-rounded-path)