# How to plot curve graph(spine graph) in android?

Tags: android, graph, achartengine, curve

I am trying to implement curve graph in android. For that i have used achartEngine library but it is providing line graph, pie graph,bar graph but not curve graph. Can you suggest some other library for curve graph?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use android plot see link  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18014834/how-to-make-line-with-rounded-smooth-corners-with-androidplot

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely draw such line charts with AChartEngine. Instead of creating a line chart view or intent, you need to create a cubic line chart one. So you will need to replace:

```
ChartFactory.getLineChartView(...);
```

with:

```
ChartFactory.getCubicLineChartView(...);
```