# LineChart issue using MPAndroidChart library

Tags: android, charts, androidplot, mpandroidchart

I am trying to make a simple smooth line chart which show the X axis as date-time on bottom and Y axis as normal left side. I just started using [MPAndroidChart API](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) and its example app in Git. In the example Line chart I am not able to find option to change X axis labels to show on bottom instead of top as show currently.

Just like:

[image]

Also is there a way to handle date-time data for X axis values ?

Also I tried my hand on Androidplot API but to make the line smooth there I need to make changes in library code which is not compiling at all in my Eclipse and giving errors. Also in Androidplot I did not find an option to show popup with data once I click on line chart.

So if anyone know how to make a smooth line chart using Androidplot API without modifying its library code and how to bring small popup with data in Androidplot API please reply.

Comment: Hey @halfer & KplMax did you get any solution on this ?

Comment: @chaitanya: I didn't have anything to add on this, it looks like I was just editing the question to improve it. KplMax hasn't logged on for a couple of months, but nevertheless he/she may see your message in due course.

Answer (score 2):

```
// XAxis settings
graph.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
graph.getXAxis().setLabelsToSkip(0);

// and
// make the line smooth
graph.getLineData().getDataSets().get(0).lineDataSet.setDrawCubic(true);
```

Comment: please consider adding some explanations

Answer (score -1):

Refer this:
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-drawing-line-chart-using-achartengine/

for smooth curve lines please refer this:

[How to make line with rounded (smooth) corners with AndroidPlot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18014834/how-to-make-line-with-rounded-smooth-corners-with-androidplot)

Hope this may help you.

**AChartEngine** is a charting library for Android applications. Using **AChartEngine** library, we can plot various charts like line chart, area chart, pie  chart, time chart, bubble chart etc.

Comment: Hi Krupa Thanks for reply but how to make smooth curve line chart using AchartEngine ? As thats an important requirement of my chart.

Comment: Hi Krupa, actually i have referred that link already issue was that the androidplot code was not compiling for me. So i switched to achartengine. Now i see that achartengine has cubic curve option, so the last important task  i am left with is, showing a popup message when i click on chart to show that y axis data. Can you tell me how to get the y axis data on a click event on chart ?

Comment: Not sure about your further needs but just in case you would like to check a different chart library that may fit: [williamchart](https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart). You can easily define a LineChart with smooth lines.

Comment: You can use Cubic line chart of Achart engine to have a smooth line chart