# Android How to get extrapolated value in an androidplot curve using SplineLineAndPointFormatter

Tags: android, androidplot

I try to find the extrapolated Y value of a point on a androidplot curve.

For example, I have three points in a array: A (0; 0) B (15; 5) C (30; 0).
I displayed in androidplot with smoothing using [SplineLineAndPointFormatter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18353513/5482809).

How can we do to find the Y value of the point N(10; ?)

Look at the [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ho03H.png)

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should not use that interpolation method because it uses cubic beziers and will plot false data.  I posted a full answer in the linked question back in 2014.

Instead you should use the [CatmullRomInterpolator](http://androidplot.com/smooth-curves-and-androidplot/).  Once you've switched over to that, you can retrieve the interpolated series by invoking `CatmullRomInterpolator.interpolate(XYSeries, Params)`.  You can then retrieve N directly from the interpolated series.