# Android Graph view with smooth corners

Tags: android, android-graphview

I am working with android GraphView version 4.2.1. I have already implemented it and have obtained a graph with sharp corners as shown in the figure.

[image: GraphView with sharp points]

How can I make it a smooth curve? 
NB : [How to make line with rounded (smooth) corners with AndroidPlot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18014834/how-to-make-line-with-rounded-smooth-corners-with-androidplot) doesn't have any relation with GraphView. Both are different libraries and they have their own unique way for it's implentation
Thanks in advance

Comment: please show images if possible for clear explaination

Comment: @AmitVaghela: Please check the update

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make line with rounded (smooth) corners with AndroidPlot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18014834/how-to-make-line-with-rounded-smooth-corners-with-androidplot)

Comment: @GhanshyamSharma : Better try to check what is AndroidPlot and GraphView

Comment: did you ever find a way to fix this ?

Comment: not yet @vlatkozelka