# AndroidPlot: XYPlot How to make Bars with rounded corners

Tags: java, android, androidplot

I am working with AndroidPlot since about one year to display different Diagrams in my app.
Now I am working with BarCharts, the charts are finished but how can I make corners rounded?

I found some results for lines:
[How to make line with rounded (smooth) corners with AndroidPlot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18014834/how-to-make-line-with-rounded-smooth-corners-with-androidplot)

I tried already:

```
BarFormatter formatter1,formatter2, formatter3;
formatter1.getBorderPaint().setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
formatter1.getFillPaint().setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
```

doesn't seems to have any impact.

then I tried:

```
XYPlot plot; //Initialized with UI-Diagrammm above
...
plot.setBorderStyle(XYPlot.BorderStyle.ROUNDED,5f,5f);
```

Does anyone had the problem already and got an answer how to do this.

Thanks for Help,

Franzi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bars are rendered by Androidplot's `BarRenderer` class which uses the `Canvas.drawRect(...)` method to draw individual bars.  In order to get rounded edges it would either need to call `Canvas.drawRoundRect` or possibly even better, draw each bar as a path using `Path.lineTo(...)` and `Path.arcTo(...)` methods so that only the top of the bars are rounded.  This functionality unfortunately does not exist yet but you could open a feature request if you want.

Or you could implement it yourself by creating a custom renderer that extends  `BarRenderer` and overriding `drawBar(...)`. [Documentation available here](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot/blob/master/docs/custom_renderer.md)

[image]

Comment: I have tried your solution, but my problem now is, that I can't find any solution to replace the Standard BarRenderer-Object with the Custom one.

Is there any known way to do this?

Thanks for Answers,

Franzi

Comment: Most likely you didnt create a custom Formatter to go along with your Renderer.  The [BarPlotExample source](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot/blob/master/demoapp/src/main/java/com/androidplot/demos/BarPlotExampleActivity.java) has a working example of how to define and use a custom Renderer

Comment: I've added a link to custom renderer documentation to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed.

Comment: Sorry for asking again but I get the following, when implementing your solution : ErrorError:(26, 20) error: name clash: drawBar(Canvas,Bar<RoundedBarFormatter>,RectF) in RoundedBarRenderer and drawBar(Canvas,Bar,RectF) in BarRenderer have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other

Comment: Most likely you just need to update to anroidplot 1.5.2